# Будет ли async await в Java?

Tags: java, async-await

Собственно вот уже год как я перешёл c С# на Java. Говорить о причинах, что жалею или нет я не буду, моё личное останется таковым со мной. Вопрос интересен мне до ужаса, собственно он в заголовке. Я понимаю что существует Kotlin, java.util.concurrent ... что тема интересующая многих. Каковы причины отсутствия async await в синтаксисе современного Java 14, 15 не говоря уже об остальных?

Может кто знает информацию о планах Oracle быть или нет async await в синтаксисе Java?

Comment: Я не утверждаю об объективности. Может кто знает инфу о планах Oracle добавить или нет его в синтаксис

Comment: `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: @МихаилРебров Да оно есть по аналогии промисов или тасков. Но это следующий шаг async await

Comment: планов Oracle я не знаю, но мне кажется что "Таков путь." (с) Мандалорец. В том смысле, что они выбрали немного другой подход.

Comment: Всем тем кто минусует, просьба оставить коментарии для улучшения качества вопроса либо ваши размышления. Не думайте что это все ради забавы выставлять вопрос и предлагать награду за ответ которого может и не быть.

Comment: Лично я плюсик поставил чтобы вопрос прожил подольше. Ибо как только вопрос появился было понятно, что он проживет недолго. И если честно то я даже удивлен тому что он до сих пор открыт. Я думаю, что свою роль сыграла огласка.  Сначала вопрос разместили на мете, потом перенесли, потом были посты на мете относительно статуса данного вопроса + конкурс. Если бы вопрос сразу опубликовали здесь, то скорее всего он бы собрал минусов и его бы втихую закрыли уже. И тут никаких шуток и забавы. Из-за таких вопросов у нас сообщество раскололось на части и ушло немало уважаемых участников.

Comment: Лично для меня все предельно ясно в данном вопросе.  В Java может появиться абсолютно всё что угодно... И у этого практически всегда будет одна причина. В Java async/await может появится моментально.. как только основные клиенты Oracle, большие дяди и тёти из банковского и финансового сектора лично Ларри Эллисону не скажут что им это нужно.

Comment: А зачем? Поведение async/await очень просто эмулировать уже имеющимися возможностями Java.

Comment: Да если вы Java девелопер. А если JS или С#

Comment: @Bakuard async await в JS и С# легко не пользоваться есть промисы и таски, но и async await также имеется и никто не говорит зачем они там нужны. Поймите промисы появились как средство избежание callback hell  а async await как средство избежания промисов

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, я согласен с вами, что эти конструкции нужны и полезны в JS (насчет C# - не знаком с этим языком, ничего не могу сказать). Но ведь вопрос был - почему их нет в Java. По моему мнению, они там просто не нужны.

Comment: @Bakuard собственно в C# такая же ситуация как и Java только в одном есть и там оно часть языка которым можно спокойно не пользоваться, а в Java его нет. Поймите одно дело вам это не надо совсем другое нельзя. Результат как бы одинаковый "нет", но разница вам наверное ясна.

Comment: Без них спокойно живётся всем языкам. Существует альтернатива у всех. Вы их не использовали и говорить о том что они не нужны. Это говорить что можно есть руками зачем вам ложка.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Вряд ли когда либо `async-await` войдут в синтаксис Java, Java довольно консервативная штука, лямбды сколько укоренялись прежде чем их взяли в синтаксис. А тут целых 2 ключевых слова - нереально.

А вот в виде библиотечных конструкций - пожалуйста. В комментах упомянули `CompletableFuture` могу добавить еще [ea-async](https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-async).

Собственно,  *таков путь (с) Мандалорец* - Java берет стабильным синтаксисом и богатством библиотек, в отличие от .NET, который непрерывно пихает в свой синтаксис что ни попадя...

**Update**

Дополню свой ответ философскими размышлениями.

1. В основе Java лежат несколько краеугольных камней: ООП, write-once, networking, security и строгость + простота. Если посмотреть на историю вопроса, то Java возникла как ответ на сложность и неуниверсальнось С++ (как бывший С++ девелопер, я когда переходил на Java был покорен именно простотой языка). Я крайне ценю то что архитекторы языка до сих пор подвержены этой философии и крайне неохотно идут на расширения синтаксиса языка и то только для простоты. Те же лямбды появились только потому, что они упрощают синтаксис.
2. Если убрать из философии Java строгость - мы получим Kotlin, где простота доведена до предела (кое-где естественно в ущерб строгости) и видя конструкцию типа:

   `val myValue = superPuperClassObject.getSomething()`

ты не понимаешь какой же тип возвращает это метод?! Ситуация в принципе немыслимая для Java в Kotlin доведена до предельного состояния и используется как способ сокращения издержек на программирование.

3. Теперь собственно к истории с `async-await`. Нет и не будет никогда `async-await` в Java как элементов синтаксиса - по причине указанной в п.1 - это разрушает концепцию простоты, это фактически будет расщеплять код на синхронный и асинхронный. По сути Java динозавр предназначенный для синхронного программирования и таковым останется, вся асинхронность вынесена в библиотеки.
4. .NET равно как и JS не имеют своей концепции - они в общем то развиваются достаточно хаотично и спонтанно, по принципу: понравилась - берем в язык. Что в общем то не умаляет их достоинств, безусловно.

Comment: Стабильность это хорошо если б язык не развивался. Но он развивается и добавляются новшества и прочая "мода". Просто дальше размышляя думается что наступит тот день когда разработчики добавят или нет в синтаксис эти 2 ключевых слова. Плюс от меня за ответ

Comment: Начиная с Java 10 есть `var`: `var myValue = superPuperClassObject.getSomething();` - так что не такая уж немыслимая ситуация) Не всегда его стоит использовать, но удобно в случаях типа `ClassName instance = new ClassName();`

Comment: @Barmaley мои поздравления. Что-то больше ответов я так и не получил увы. Сообщество решило что 100 это ваши. Я ничего против общества ничего не имею. :))

Comment: Ну с таким "активным" сообществом ничего иного ожидать не приходится. Мало отвечающих, еще меньше тех кто задает хорошие вопросы

Comment: @Barmaley да есть такое вот подумываю свалить отсюда.

Comment: Не надо сваливать - останься :)

Answer (score 5):

Вот что я нашел на просторах [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075295/why-does-java-have-no-async-await) (свободный перевод)

Короткий ответ заключается в том, что разработчики Java стараются устранить необходимость в асинхронных методах вместо того, чтобы облегчить их использование.

Согласно докладу Рона Пресслера, асинхронное программирование с использованием CompletableFuture вызывает три основные проблемы.

1. ветвление или зацикливание результатов вызовов асинхронных методов невозможно
2. нельзя использовать stacktraces для выявления источника ошибок, профилирование становится невозможным
3. это вирусно: все методы, которые выполняют асинхронные вызовы, также должны быть асинхронными, т.е. синхронный и асинхронный миры не смешиваются

Хотя async / await решает первую проблему, он может только частично решить вторую проблему и не решает вообще третью проблему (например, все методы в C #, выполняющие awit, должны быть помечены как async).

Но зачем вообще нужно асинхронное программирование? Только для предотвращения блокировки потоков. Таким образом, вместо того, чтобы вводить async / await в Java, в проекте Loom Java-дизайнеры работают над волокнами (fibers) (также известными как легкие потоки), которые будут стремиться значительно снизить стоимость потоков и тем самым устранить необходимость в асинхронном программировании. Это сделало бы все три вышеупомянутые проблемы также устаревшими.

PS. Складывается впечатление что разработчики C# и JS отталкиваются от других принципов.

Comment: Пока джава дизайнеры работают над некими волшебными волокнами, которые безусловно решат все проблемы и не принесут новых, пишется сотни тысяч и миллионов строк кода, тысячи библиотек -- без учёта и знания этих волокон. Т.е. когда волокна увидят свет, ни одна библиотека и не один проект ничего про это знать не будет и не поддерживать ни в каком виде. А между тем, время идёт, у ранее молодых разработчиков уже дети появились,и внуки -- может правнуки и увидят файберы и поучаствуют в радостном переписывании всего и вся на новые рельсы, это же так прекрасно. В то время как в c# уже много лет все би